# How do I convert HEXADECIMAL to DECIMAL in SAS?

Tags: sql, sas, sas-gtl

*I have:*
A string with hexadecimal values ​​every 4 positions

**00F701C101C900EC01E001D2**

*I need:*

Separate these values ​​from 4 in 4 positions and convert to decimal numbers in this way:

**247, 449, 457, 480, 466**

My column can have up to 1200 hexadecimal positions

Can you help me?

Tks!!!

Comment: What did you try? It what ways did it not work?

Comment: please put in some code that you tried.

Comment: I know EXCEL only, I could not do it by SAS

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
data out;
    hex = "00F701C101C900EC01E001D2";
    do while(hex ne "");
        valHex = substr(hex, 1, 4);
        hex = substr(hex, 5);
        valDec = input(valHex, hex4.);
        output;
    end;
run;
```

but you'll want to add more error checking etc for your real solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was to fast. This is SQL-Server syntax, probably not working for you, but you might get an idea...

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @YourString VARCHAR(100)='00F701C101C900EC01E001D2';
WITH Separated AS
(
    SELECT CAST(LEFT(@YourString,4) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS SourceString
          ,CAST(SUBSTRING(@YourString,5,10000) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS RestString
    UNION ALL
    SELECT LEFT(RestString,4) 
          ,SUBSTRING(RestString,5,10000)
    FROM Separated
    WHERE LEN(RestString)>=4
)
SELECT *
      ,CAST(sys.fn_cdc_hexstrtobin(SourceString) AS VARBINARY(2))
      ,CAST(CAST(sys.fn_cdc_hexstrtobin(SourceString) AS VARBINARY(2)) AS INT)
FROM Separated
```

The result

```
+--------------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| SourceString | RestString           | (Kein Spaltenname) | (Kein Spaltenname) |
+--------------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 00F7         | 01C101C900EC01E001D2 | 0x00F7             | 247                |
+--------------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 01C1         | 01C900EC01E001D2     | 0x01C1             | 449                |
+--------------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 01C9         | 00EC01E001D2         | 0x01C9             | 457                |
+--------------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 00EC         | 01E001D2             | 0x00EC             | 236                |
+--------------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 01E0         | 01D2                 | 0x01E0             | 480                |
+--------------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 01D2         |                      | 0x01D2             | 466                |
+--------------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Tks Shnugo! 
I'll check and share the results!!